# Неправильная инициализация вектора

Tags: c++, инициализация

Код:

```
static bool AmxLoad(AMX* amx)
{
    amx_List.amx = amx;
    amx_FindPublic(amx, "OnPlayerCommandReceived", &amx_List.OPCR);
    amx_FindPublic(amx, "OnPlayerCommandPerfomed", &amx_List.OPCP);
    const std::vector<AMX_NATIVE_INFO> PluginNatives =
    {
        { "scmd", &amx_scmd }
    };
    amx_Register(amx, PluginNatives.data(), PluginNatives.size());
    return AMX_ERR_NONE;
}
```

Ошибки:

> Ошибка    1   error C2552: PluginNatives: инициализация не агрегированных данных с помощью списка инициализации не допускается    c:\users\anatoliy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lightcommandprocessor\lightcommandprocessor\main.cpp    71  1   LightCommandProcessor
>
> Ошибка    2   error C2078: слишком много
>   инициализаторов   c:\users\anatoliy\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\lightcommandprocessor\lightcommandprocessor\main.cpp    72  1   LightCommandProcessor
>
> Ошибка  3 IntelliSense: инициализация объектов типа "const
>   std::vector>" с
>   помощью выражения {...} не
>   допускается   c:\users\anatoliy\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\lightcommandprocessor\lightcommandprocessor\main.cpp    71  3   LightCommandProcessor

Comment: напишите код руками или копипаст.

Comment: а текст ошибки: цитатой

Comment: А теперь то же самое, текстом и с [минимальным примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - чтобы было понятно, что к чему и можно было воспроизвести у себя...

Comment: Готово, все что написали я сделал.

Comment: А, ну так VS 2010 никак не понимает такие вещи, как инициализация в фигурных скобках C++11.

Comment: Скачивать новую вску, или можно как то исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш компилятор слишком стар и не умеет работать с новинками С++11, к каковым относится инициализация в фигурных скобках. В VC++ вы должны объявить пустой вектор и добавить в него нужное значение.

Только объясните, зачем вам вектор **из одного элемента**? Почему бы не использовать просто сам элемент и передать в `amx_Register` указатель на него?

Comment: Все ясно, а какая версия требуется?

Comment: Ну, например, 2017 или 2015. Лучше - если уж меняете - берите 2017, там уже даже куски С++17 реализованы.